# Como hago que una url se ajuste a un contenedor

Tags: email, nodemailer

Estoy haciendo un mailing y tengo una url muy larga. quisiera ajustar esta url a un contenedor

```
<a href="liunga">
https://loremipsumdolor.sit/amet/consectetur/adipisicing/elit/Blanditiis/animi/doloribus/ipsum/asperiores/eum/enim/corporis/nostrum/error/ipsam/Hic/a/neque/Saepe/rem/placeat/facere/velit/distinctio/dicta/totam
</a>
```

```html
<a style="width: 300px !important;" href="loremipsumdolor.sit/amet/consectetur/adipisicing/elit/Blanditiis/animi/doloribus/ipsum/asperiores/eum/enim/corporis/nostrum/error/ipsam/Hic/a/neque/Saepe/rem/placeat/facere/velit/distinctio/dicta/totam">
https://loremipsumdolor.sit/amet/consectetur/adipisicing/elit/Blanditiis/animi/doloribus/ipsum/asperiores/eum/enim/corporis/nostrum/error/ipsam/Hic/a/neque/Saepe/rem/placeat/facere/velit/distinctio/dicta/totam
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<a style="width: 300px; display: block; overflow-wrap: break-word" href="loremipsumdolor.sit/amet/consectetur/adipisicing/elit/Blanditiis/animi/doloribus/ipsum/asperiores/eum/enim/corporis/nostrum/error/ipsam/Hic/a/neque/Saepe/rem/placeat/facere/velit/distinctio/dicta/totam">
https://loremipsumdolor.sit/amet/consectetur/adipisicing/elit/Blanditiis/animi/doloribus/ipsum/asperiores/eum/enim/corporis/nostrum/error/ipsam/Hic/a/neque/Saepe/rem/placeat/facere/velit/distinctio/dicta/totam
</a>
```

Te sirven dos propiedades `display: block` para convertir el display original de la etiqueta a que es `inline` a `block` con esto tu contenedor adoptará el tamaño necesario, luego el  `overflow-wrap: break-word` te permitirá que el texto se adapte al contenedor.

Comment: Vale. Que genial. El tamaño del contenedor esta bien en 600px. Como comento lo utilizare para un maling. **muchas gracias por tu ayuda**

Comment: Si consideras que resuelvo tu pregunta podrías votarla como respuesta :)